# Netty message execution in parallel on EmbeddedChannel

Tags: netty

Our program is a server and a client at the same time and has one bootstrapped server and multiple bootstrapped clients.

Now we want to split our program into two layers. Layer 1 handles all messages for every connection/channel and should pass everything at the end to layer 2. Layer 2 accumulates, therefore all the given messages from layer 1 and should be something like an EmbeddedChannel because we want to use the netty pipeline to intercept the message from all connections in handlers (and don't want to write our own pipeline). See also the attached figure.

[image: 2-Layer-Model figure]

But the EmbeddedChannel is single-core, we want to have something like a ThreadPool that executes messages in parallel on layer 2. How could that be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the "local" transport for this. Check out the `LocalChannel` / `LocalServerChannel`